# wp_transition_post_status does not change the status of the post

Tags: plugin-development, actions, post-status

For some reason, I have to unpublish certain posts every time wordpress loads. 
This is my code:

```
function af_change_post_status() {
    $notpayed_posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'meta_key'                  =>  '_payment',
        'meta_value'                =>  '0'
    ) );

    foreach ($notpayed_posts as $notpayed_post) {
        wp_transition_post_status( 'draft', $notpayed_post->post_status, $notpayed_post);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'af_change_post_status' );
```

The query is correct and it's returning the posts I want, but the `wp_transition_post_status` function is not working and I don't know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This function contains do_action() calls for post status transition
>   action hooks. The order of the words in the function name might be
>   confusing – **it does not change the status of posts, it only calls
>   actions that can be hooked into by plugin developers.**

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_transition_post_status

What you want is `wp_update_post`, you're also using `WP_Query` incorrectly:

```
    $notpayed_posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'meta_key'                  =>  '_payment',
        'meta_value'                =>  '0'
    ) );

```
while ($notpayed_posts->have_posts()) {
    $notpayed_posts->the_post();
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => get_the_ID(),
        'post_status' => 'draft'
    ));
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also, keep in mind that your query is an expensive/very slow post meta query, post meta isn't built for searching or queries where you're looking for posts. Consider a taxonomy term.

You also do nothing to change the meta afterwards, so if there are 10 posts that match, then every page load will try to update 10 posts, even if they've already been updated! Either change the meta value with `update_post_meta` or check the post status in the query, e.g.

```
$notpayed_posts = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_status'               =>  'publish',
    'meta_key'                  =>  '_payment',
    'meta_value'                =>  '0'
) );
```

Additionally, use a cron job, don't do it on every page load by using the `init` hook, it's very bad for performance and incompatible with page caching

Comment: Thank you for the good answer, `wp_update_post` first parameter was not in the codex though.

Comment: @Amirition you're right, it needs to be an ID parameter in the array as shown in the example. Note that `wp_update_post` is a thin wrapper around `wp_insert_post` which can also be used to modify existing posts

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple error. You use `WP_Query` to get posts, but then you try to use that `WP_Query` object as an array, but this class doesn't implement iterator, AFAIR.

```
function af_change_post_status() {
    $notpayed_posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'meta_key'                  =>  '_payment',
        'meta_value'                =>  '0'
    ) );

    foreach ($notpayed_posts->posts as $notpayed_post) {
        wp_transition_post_status( 'draft', $notpayed_post->post_status, $notpayed_post);
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'af_change_post_status' );
```

This should work better (if your query is correct).